# Detected a hung GPU, disabling acceleration

Tags: lubuntu, intel, gpu, crash

on lubutnu 14.04

im getting a gpu hang on lubuntu and when  i checked the system log it said

[  2303.921] (EE) intel(0): Detected a hung GPU, disabling acceleration.
[  2303.922] (EE) intel(0): When reporting this, please include /sys/class/drm/card0/error and the full dmesg.

which i have included  a link to  below

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzQi9W8TqGacZGNfUURTVU5ZdDg/edit?usp=sharing

I have found a temporay solution in setting closed lid action to suspend as waking from suspend reawakens the screen

does anyone have a permant solution to stop it from hanging in the first place 
thanks

Comment: Welcome to AU! The error message advises you to include the output of `sudo dmesg` when your report this issue. You can [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/531591/edit) your question to include additional info.

Comment: black screen happens to me, my output of dmesg is here, http://pastebin.com/byFXpUdN

Comment: no error state collected in /sys/class/drm/card0/error

Comment: I have a similar problem, did this start recently? Have you opened a bug report beyond this?